# Defining $e$ using derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis

I find the current definition of $e$ for high school pupils a bit useless. Namely $e=\lim\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n$.

I was thinking on another definition. If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is differentiable and $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1$ then $e=f(1)$.

My question is about if that one is really a proper definition of $e$ and what it would be the proof. That is: the function $f$ does exist and $f(1)$ is at $[2,3]$ or something like that.

Comment: It's perfectly feasible, but you've got the non-trivial task of showing $f'=f$ with $f(0)=1$ has a unique solution.  I think some French analysis texts do this ??Dieudonne.

Comment: I think the definition is fine, but I disagree with your statement that the definition for high school is useless. That definition is what allows students to evaluate basic limits of quotients such as $\ln(1+x)/x \to 1$ and $(e^x - 1)/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$. These limits, in turn, allow us to differentiate the logarithm and exponential functions.

Comment: @Ssay But the existence of the limit is a bit difficult to show for those pupils. Too much topolgy is needed.

Comment: @ajotatxe ah, that bit I agree. One could start from your differential equation above and show that the function $f$ satisfies all the properties of an exponential function - If i recall correctly, I believe that is how W. Rudin explains $e$.

Comment: How about use the series? $e^x= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$
or make the superior limit of the summation n goes to infinity. This way they can calculate approximations and show every other propertie of $e^x$

Comment: @RenjiRodrigo I took this way some times. But then proving that $De^x=e^x$ becomes very difficult.

Comment: everything regarding the exponential function (or the number $e$) requires something non-trivial. Either existence/uniqueness of ODEs, or existence/uniqueness of a certain (continuous) extension of a functional equation, or existence of a certain limit. Depending on where you start and how many theorems you have at your disposal (particularly for dealing with multiple limits and their exchange) you’ll have an easier/harder time proving properties about differentiability.